# decimal module - decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>] when n = float

Tags: python-3.x, math

I have a script that uses the [Binet formula](http://web.ist.utl.pt/%7Ecatarina.p.moreira/images/binet.png) to calculate the Nth number of the Fibonacci sequence.

The function is this:

```
import decimal as d
def compute_binet(gold, n):
    numerator = (
        d.Decimal(gold) ** d.Decimal(n)) -\
        ((d.Decimal(-1) / d.Decimal(gold)) ** d.Decimal(n)
    )
    denominator = d.Decimal(5).sqrt()

    return numerator / denominator
```

if I call the function like this: `compute_binet(gold, 5)`

there are no issues.

if I call the function like this: `compute_binet(gold, 5.5)`

i get: `decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]`

Stacktrace:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "binet.py", line 142, in <module>
    try: upTime = MAIN()
  File "binet.py", line 98, in MAIN
    answer = compute_binet(compute_golden(100), n)
  File "binet.py", line 122, in compute_binet
    ((d.Decimal(-1) / d.Decimal(gold)) ** d.Decimal(n)
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]
```

When I look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) it seems that perhaps it's that the syntax needs to be `Decimal('5.5')`.

So I tried using the .format method

```
import decimal as d
def compute_binet(gold, n):
    numerator = (
        d.Decimal(gold) ** d.Decimal('{}'.format(n))) -\
        ((d.Decimal(-1) / d.Decimal(gold)) ** d.Decimal('{}'.format(n))
    )
    denominator = d.Decimal(5).sqrt()

    return numerator / denominator
```

This still did not work. Any ideas of how I can input numbers with decimals into that formula using the Decimal method?

Note: I thought maybe it was a type error, so I tried converting var `n` to decimal type by using `n = d.Decimal(n)` after getting user input. No luck there either.

Comment: Note that the docs for this error [explicitly mention that ``x ** (non-integer)``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.InvalidOperation) may be invalid.

Comment: More specific: it returns the error when the base is negative _AND_ the exponent is a fraction.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi darn. do you think this means there is no solution using the decimal module? i tried looking and results are always mentioning using other methods for calculating non-integer exponents.

Comment: @Ronald Unfortunately the Binet formula requires this; at least I cannot think of a math trick to get around it and comply with that rule.

I wonder why they did not make that possible when coding up the module / updating it. :/

Comment: Can't help that. But do you really need the Decimal module?

Comment: @Ronald i just need one with all the basic math functions and is super precise and has customizable precision for calculating irrational numbers.

If you have a module you would recommend that does those things, I'm all ears!